# What is the deal with the bizarre philosophy in historical and current axiomatic set theory?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, philosophy

Many respectable mathematicians have written about "true axioms" or similar concerns about whether all mathematical theorems are in fact "real" or "true".  This seems to make a great deal of non-sense to me, to the point where I suspect I must be missing something.  Historically (and to a lesser extent recently) mathematicians made a great fuss about Choice, and recently Continuum and large cardinal axioms are debated.  This would be at least somewhat more understandable if the debate was about whether it is *more interesting or useful* to study the consequences of different mathematical systems, but instead the debate frequently consists of justifications about "what is mathematical reality as opposed to a falsehood" or "what is intuitively obvious and therefore true", etc.  This entire situation seems ridiculous to me.  I don't understand how it isn't the case that all axiom sets are equally "true", or more like the entire framing is bizarre to me.  We don't speak of fields being more "true" than groups, or lattices, or quandles, or what have you.  We also don't really argue about it being "better" to study groups than fields, but it at least does not seem so much like nonsense.  Why is it not the case that working in ZF or NBG or whatever set theory simply other branches of mathematics studying theorems on different objects?  How does the concept of "mathematical reality" make any sense at all?  Being confronted with brilliant minds frankly worrying about such things makes me assume there must be something I, a newcomer to logic and set theory, am simply yet to grasp about the matter.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could cite at least one or two examples of respectable mathematicians writing about "true axioms" or similar concerns.

Comment: @MJD I suppose "respectable" is just an assumption on my part.  It could be that this is not the case.

Comment: Examples would be helpful, but keep in mind that many mathematicians could be said to be "formalists in the street, Platonists in the sheets". They may be working in a purely formalist "axioms are neither true nor false, just the rules of the game" setting, but in their hearts of hearts they want axioms to represent some kind of "absolute truth".

Comment: ... that said, perhaps you should drop the "bizarre" from the title.

Comment: I'm not trying to dispute your claim, I just want to see the examples so that I know what you are referring to.

Comment: @MJD The specific inciting article that I read was Believing the Axioms, Maddy, 1988 in the Journal of Symbolic Logic, which is in large part a discussion of other authors' opinions.  Other things I've read have contributed to this conception I have, but the more I think about it the more I realize that I don't actually know of any more current examples aside from authors championing constructivism who I know to be a minority.  It may very well be more of a historical question.

Comment: On the same subject, you might be interested in [George Boolos'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boolos) essay on whether we are required to believe in $\kappa$, which he defines as the smallest set whose cardinality is $\aleph_\kappa$. (That is, it is the fixed point of the mapping $n\mapsto \aleph_n$.)  Boolos is certainly a respectable mathematician. I forget the title of the essay but it was collected in [Logic, Logic, and Logic](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/books/9780674537675) (1999).

Comment: It's the Platonic view, that Mathematics is a natural science describing the physical world.  Why is Mathematics useful in branches of physical sciences?  Why can we convince each other of mathematical or logical conclusions if they're only illusions in our mind?  What is it about the human brain that makes us understand it and reach agreement about it?  Do animals understand math on some level?

Comment: @ChadK Mathematics is useful in physical sciences because it is a vast field of study of the systematic connections between various things, and some of these things are useful models of reality, yknow?  I don't know what "only illusions in our mind" means.  We can use language to communicate abstract ideas, this does not seem particularly mystifying to me.  Any animal is theoretically capable of it, perhaps humans are the only ones who have evolved those capacities, it really depends who you ask.  None of these questions are even remotely relevant *within the realm of math itself*, though.

Comment: The point of foundations is to have a foundation for all of mathematics. So, having different foundational theories studying different objects defeats the purpose. Also, it doesn't really matter. Whether one is a Platonist, Formalist, etc... you can't tell from the mathematics you actually do. So, the actual work is unaffected.

Comment: “having different foundational theories studying different objects defeats the purpose” seems like a strange thing to say since there _are_ different foundational theories studying different objects.

Comment: @MayEmerson: It appears that there is a great risk of your question being deleted, presumably because some users read it as more of a rant than a question (though I don't personally hold that view). Would you mind if I edited your question in the hope of "saving" it? I would not like to see an answer as good as Andreas's to be deleted.

Answer (score 12):

There are two sorts of axiom systems. Axioms of the first sort are intended to describe the important properties of some particular mathematical structure. Examples include Euclid's axioms for geometry (intended to describe the space in which we live), Peano's axioms (intended to describe the natural numbers), and Zermelo's axioms (intended to describe the universe of sets).

For a long time, all axiom systems were of this sort, but toward the end of the 19th century people began to use axioms for a different purpose. Axioms of this second sort are intended to describe important properties of a whole class of structures. The motivation for this was the observation that sometimes structures that are clearly very different (for example the integers versus the polynomials in one variable over the complex numbers) nevertheless share some properties and, further, that proofs of these properties look very similar in these different contexts (e.g., the proof that principal ideal domains have unique prime factorization). So it became useful to write down axioms summarizing some basic properties common to many systems (e.g., axioms defining what a principal ideal domain is) as the starting point for deductions (e.g., of unique factorization) that would apply to many contexts.

For axioms of the second sort, it makes no sense to ask about their truth or falsity. One can talk about truth or falsity in a particular structure (e.g., the principal ideal domain axioms are true in the ring of integers but false in the ring of polynomials in $2$ or more variables over the complex numbers). Since these axioms are intended to summarize important properties of some structures, they will be true in those structures and false in others. Deducing other properties from the axioms is an efficient way to prove those properties for all structures that satisfy the axioms. In this way, axioms are particularly useful if many structures satisfy them (and therefore satisfy everything deducible from these axioms), and then it is to be expected that some additional statements are satisfied by some but not all of the many structures that satisfy the axioms. Such additional properties will be undecidable from the axioms.

The situation is quite different for axiom systems of the first sort, systems intended to describe one particular structure. Their purpose is not aided by being satisfied in other structures; indeed, the purpose may be hindered, because one might then want to add more axioms to exclude those extraneous structures and thus describe the desired structure more precisely.

For axiom systems of this first sort, one is usually interested primarily in truth or falsity in the one structure that the axioms were designed to describe. When people talk about "truth" in the context of such axiom systems, they mean truth in that one particular structure. Deductions from the axioms, which were the whole purpose of the second sort of axioms, are also  a very useful tool for establishing that some statement is true in this sense (i.e., true in the original structure that the axioms were designed to describe), and for convincing other people of that, but they are not the only tool. For example, someone who knows that the ZFC axioms are true of the universe of sets also knows that the statement "ZFC is consistent" is true, even though it cannot be deduced from ZFC (by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem).

In connection with axioms of the first sort, people (very probably including you) are much more likely to say that "$2+2=4$" is true than to say that it's deducible from the Peano axioms. The reason "true" is meaningful in this context is that we have a common understanding of the structure that the Peano axioms are intended to describe (the natural numbers), and we've known that $2+2=4$ since we were little children, long before we heard of Peano or deductions.

I view the situation with ZFC and sets as analogous to the situation with the Peano axioms and natural numbers. I have an understanding of what ZFC is intended to describe, the universe of sets, and "true" means truth in that universe. Notice also that non-trivial theorems about sets were proved before Zermelo formulated the axiom system that would grow to become ZFC. For example, it was known that no set can be mapped onto its power set well before Zermelo found it necessary to state axioms about sets.

Of course, I don't claim to understand the universe of sets as well as I understand the natural number system, but this looks to me like a quantitative difference: How much do I understand? Qualitatively, the two are the same sort of understanding. So I'm willing to talk about truth in the set-theoretic context just as I'm willing to talk about truth on the number-theoretic context. And I would be very happy if
I could improve my understanding of the set-theoretic universe enough to know whether the cardinality of the continuum is $\aleph_1$ or not.

Finally, let me echo Joe Shoenfield's statement in the preface of his wonderful book "Mathematical Logic": "I will offer no apology, however, if I have occasionally stated a philosophical opinion without observing that the contrary opinion is also widely held."

Comment: This is at least comprehensible to me, but I am stumped by the implication that there is some universe of sets independent of its axiomatic basis... how can you claim such a thing?  I understand that independent axiomatic systems may be isomorphic in various ways, but that's not the same thing at all, is it?  In what sense could the 'truth' of the cardinality of the continuum be judged if not by the fundamental axioms?

Comment: As for the truth of "2 + 2 = 4" it is just semantics really...  Whether someone is thinking of 2 + 2 = 4 as a theorem produced from formal axioms or an observation that in many everyday circumstances you take two objects and then add another two to it, you now have four objects doesn't really matter, though I would tend to think in the first way considering this arithmetic doesn't always hold up in reality. The point is that the systems in reality that can be modeled by this arithmetic are commonly understood. There's also systems in reality that can be accurately modeled by 2 + 2 = 3, though!

Comment: Also, I skipped over this, but I thought ZFC has never been proven consistent in *any* axiomatic system!?

Comment: @MayEmerson About your first comment: I claim the existence of a universe of sets independent of its axiomatic "basis" in the same way that I claim the existence of the set of integers independent of its axiomatic "basis". I put the word "basis" in quotes because I think it's misleading, as if we first concocted some axioms and then imagined a structure to fit them.  In my opinion, the structure comes first and the axioms are then invented to describe the structure. (This applies to what I called the first sort of axioms in the answer, like Euclid's, Peano's, and Zermelo's.)

Comment: About "commonly understood" in your second comment, this looks to me like another merely quantitative distinction. It's probably true that more people understand natural numbers than understand sets, but is that philosophically important? Also, unlike you, I think the difference between  truth and provability matters a lot for axiom systems of the first kind. Gödel's theorems guarantee that no such axiom system can produce all the truths. Provable statements from reasonable axioms can algorithmically listed; truths, even about the natural numbers, cannot.

Comment: About your third comment: The consistency of ZFC can be proved in other reasonable axiom systems, for example Morse-Kelley class theory, or ZFC plus the existence an inaccessible cardinal. (Both of these have been used in mathematics outside set theory.) Of course, such an axiom system has to include some axiom not provable in ZFC, by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150185/discussion-between-may-emerson-and-andreas-blass).

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I find your position interesting. I wonder if you could clarify the following points: in your answer, you assert that you know that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, and this is one example of a statement which you know to be true, even though it is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Are there any other statements which you claim that you know to be true of the set-theoretic universe, say the existence of uncountable inacessible cardinals, even though they are independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: You also appear to advocate the idea that there is one set-theoretic universe, i.e. a single intended model of the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms. Given the recent rise in popularity of the multiverse viewpoint, is there a reason why you find the idea that there is a single intended interpretation of the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms more compelling?

Comment: @Joe People can intend different things, so I see no problem when some people think ZFC has a single intended model while others think it has many. My preference for the "one" viewpoint comes, at least in part, from the idea that ZFC is intended to describe the cumulative hierarchy: Transfinitely iterate **forever** adding as sets **all collections** of previously formed sets. The boldface parts here are admittedly vague, but they nevertheless imply the correctness of the ZFC axioms.

Comment: @Joe There are, of course, many other structures that satisfy the ZFC axioms. But they are (for me) not the intended model. For example, Gödel's L is obtained by iterating forever the process of adding all **definable** collections of previously formed sets. Boolean-valued models add (not sets but) Boolean-valued sets. Ultrapowers (usually --- absent measurable cardinals) add some non-sets (ill-founded sets). Etc. In each of these cases, it's a theorem that these alternate models satisfy the ZFC axioms.

Comment: @Joe You asked about how much I know, beyond ZFC. I thought  about this for a while and didn't find a clear boundary. I think the boundary is still ab it fuzzy. What I can say is that I believe that no phenomenon should arise at the end of the cumulative hierarchy unless it has already arisen previously, As a consequence, I believe there are plenty of inaccessible cardinals, indescribable cardinals, etc. (I don't think I **know** these things; they are my current opinion.)

Comment: @Joe On the other hand, I have  not been able to justify for myself the existence of large cardinals whose definition involves  some combinatorial structure that then implies largeness. So I'm not yet convinced that measurable cardinals exist. Indeed, I"m not even convinced about subtle cardinals, which are so weak that, if they exist at  all, then they exist in L.